# ¿Cómo ver un repositorio que apunta a un dominio hacia un subdominio?

Tags: git, plesk

Tengo un proyecto que actualmente está en fase de desarrollo. Estoy utilizando *git* y cada vez que hago un `push` de los cambios realizados, se hace el *deploy* en *my-domain.com*, no obstante, ahora se quiere mover a *project.my-domain.com*

¿Cómo puedo hacer para no perder todo el historial de cambios?

La única forma que se me ocurre es:

Crear un repositorio vacío en el servidor y hacer un `push` de todos los cambios, aunque no sé si es la forma correcta de hacerlo.

En mi servidor utilizo *Plesk* como gestor.

Comment: Si, tal cual lo estás describiendo. Puedes crear otro repositorio (o los que necesites) y empujar las ramas/etiquetas que consideres.... git no se _confunde_, digamos.

Comment: Y, para redondear, lo que haces es agregar un _remoto_ a tu repositorio local y entonces empujas a ese nuevo remoto... por ejemplo: `git remote add nuevo el-url-al-nuevo-repo; git push -a nuevo` (para que suba todas las ramas de un solo tanganazo (o ir nombrando cada una de las ramas/etiquetas en el push).